# Tax Rules for Gifts from Abroad

Tags: taxes, canada, international-transfer, international

Are there additional taxes for receiving gifts (under $100,000) from abroad?

My uncles (in the source country) and my mother (in Canada) inherited some real estate in the source country.  My mother's name is not listed as an owner or beneficiary.  My uncles sold the property and are now splitting the proceeds across the family.

Assuming all taxation rules around inheritance and capital property have been followed in the source country, the amount we would receive would be post-tax.

Would we have to pay any additional taxes/fees (beyond electronic funds transfer service fees) for receiving my mother's share as a "gift?"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Consult with a tax lawyer in your Mother's country familiar with inheriting foreign funds.

Comment: Thanks for responding Xalorous.  The funds have already been taxed in my uncle's country (the source of the funds).  My mother is with me in Canada.  Upon transferring the funds to Canada, would we be subject to additional taxes in Canada?

Comment: The penalties for using the wrong answer in the realm of taxes are often severe, thus the answer is ask an expert in your country.  Tax lawyer or an accountant specializing in taxes.

Comment: This hinges heavily on tax treaties, I suspect, so professional advice is advised.

Comment: Following on from @PhillipSiebold's comment: from what I have picked up here, some (pairs of) countries have reciprocal arrangements so that taxes paid in one country offset/cancel taxes that would otherwise be due in another. Whether "source country" has such arrangements with Canada could greatly affect the position (hence the recommendation to seek expert advice).